# On Solr Cloud(with zookeeper setup) a perticular node tlog fille growing unexceptionaly

Tags: solr, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have cluster of 7 nodes (6 solr + 1 zookeper) in my local system setup. My used configuration is solr 5.5.0 and zookeeper-3.4.8. Actually I am having a testing environment in local before moving to production environment. For that I have created 6 instances of solr  as well as Zookeeper (1 instance of each on a laptop) and 1 instance of zookeeper especially on a laptop. Now when I test it in local using soap request My 1 node's tlog have unexceptional size at same time rest are fine.

what can be issue, how should I approach to rectify. I am not able to understand what is problem because my rest nodes are fine except one node.

Note:- Every machine(laptop) have same solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Please provide more information. How is cluster setup? Replication or Sharded? How are you indexing the documents?

Comment: Unexceptional is not a state of concern. Also, why not Solr 8 and why Solr 5.5?